# How can I make a request with both GET and POST parameters in PHP with cURL?

Tags: php, post, curl, get

Other people have already asked how to do this from perl, java, bash, etc. but I need to do it in PHP, and I don't see any question already asked relating specifically to (or with answers for) PHP.

My code:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This doesn't work. The destination site has `print_r($_GET); print_r($_POST);`, so when I examine the `$result` I should be able to see the fields that are  being sent. However, the $_POST array is empty - I only see the get variables. If I remove the `?...` query string from the $url, then the POST array is populated correctly. But now I don't have the GET params. How do I do this?

My specific case is, I need to send too much data to fit it in the query string, but I can't send it all as POST because the site I want to submit to is selecting a handler for the posted data based on a variable in the GET string. I can try and have that changed, but ideally I would like to be able to send both get and post data in the same query.

Comment: http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/

Comment: You can't perform a POST and a GET at the same time, you can add some querystring params to your url however, but to add POST vars, you have to do a POST.

Comment: @ParagTyagi Yes, that's a very nice basic tutorial, but it doesn't address my question - how do I send GET and POST *at the same time*?

Comment: You can't, but don't let PHP's `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals confuse you into thinking that a query string is a special GET request thing.

Comment: @Benubird You should read up on how HTTP works to really understand this.  There is only one verb per request.  As Quentin and Dan said, you can have variables in the query string and still use the POST verb.

Comment: @Brad Ok, so how do I make $_GET have the values from the query string, and $_POST have the values that are posted?

Comment: @Benubird Exactly what everyone has said... POST to a URL with a query string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# GET query goes in the URL you're hitting
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/script.php?query=parameter');
# POST fields go here.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('post' => 'parameter', 'values' => 'go here'));
```

PHP itself wouldn't decide to ignore the GET parameters if a POST is performed. It'll populate $_GET regardless of what kind of http verb was used to load the page - if there's query parameters in the URL, they'll go into $_GET.

If you're not getting $_POST and $_GET with this, then something is causing a redirect or otherwise killing something. e.g. have you check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to see if your code is actually running as a POST? PHP won't populate $_POST if a post wasn't actually performed. You may have sent a post to the server, but that doesn't mean your code will actually be executed under a POST regime - e.g. a mod_rewrite redirect.

Since you have FOLLOW_REDIRECT turned on, you're simply ASSUMING you're actually getting a post when your code executes.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it *doesn't work*! Am I missing something? Is there some special php.ini setting I need?

Comment: @Benubird No, there is no special setting.  This is how it works, and if it isn't working for you should post your actual code.  Nowhere in your code do you show your URL.  It definitely works, so your URL must be incorrect.

Comment: @Brad This is my url: `https://ec2-54-225-37-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com/wordpress/?wc-api=paddle_wc_payment_gateway`

Comment: Try that URL from the command line with `curl -I` or similar to see response headers. You're almost certainly getting redirected.

Comment: Yes. the answer was, my url was missing a trailing slash, and it was automatically redirecting me to add it, apparently losing the post data in the process. I assumed that followlocation meant redo the post on the new url, apparently not.

Comment: no. a 30x redirect will also request the new url as a get. There is 307, which SHOULD redirect as a POSt, but it's not widely known/supported.

Comment: Right, that's the problem - it needs to send both get and post fields, but is only sending the get ones. It's a 301 redirect, which is apparently being sent as get instead of post.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know maybe you already have but is your $url has the desired get parameters? Like:

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2";
```

Comment: Yes, it does - like I said in the question, I can see either the post fields or the get fields, but not both.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @randomizer How does it not?

Comment: @Brad, because Benubird is passing the get variables like this but only sees GET or POST with his current script.
Read the question..
He stats he removes the ? querystring so I assume he already passes get parameters like this answer.

Comment: @randomizer I did read his question, and nowhere does he indicate that he is actually doing this.  If he did, it would work.  It's very simple.

Comment: @Brad, yes he does, read again: " If I remove the ?... query string from the $url, t...."

Comment: @randomizer this **is** the answer. Run it to disprove it.

Comment: @randomizer I did read that.  My point is that nowhere in his code sample is the actual value of `$url`.  In any case, he figured out his problem was that his URL was wrong.