# Put GET values in PHP Curl request header

Tags: php, curl

The API I'm requesting is expecting a `GET` HTTP method

I want to avoid something like

`domain.com/api/v1/module/user?access_token=er78e9wr7fasf7s9a8fsd7fa8f7sa8f` for example.

I'd rather be able to request

`domain.com/api/v1/module/user`
and set the access_token value in the header, I'm aware you can do this with post, but I'd like to do this for a GET method.

I currently have the following

```
    public function fetch() 
    {
        $response = json_decode(
            $this->prepareRequest(
                new \Web\Curl\Wrapper,
                $this->prepareRequestURL()
            )->execute()
        );
    }
    private function prepareRequestURL()
    {
        return $this->apiConfig->getBaseDomain() . $this->apiConfig->getUserSelfURL();
    }

    private function prepareRequest(\Web\Curl\Wrapper $curlWrapper, $url)
    {
        $curlWrapper->init($url);
        $curlWrapper->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $curlWrapper->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            $this->apiConfig->getAccessTokenKey() => $_SESSION[$this->apiConfig->getAccessTokenKey()]
        ));
        return $curlWrapper;
    }
```

My curl wrapper class

```
private $curl;

public function init($requestLocation = null)
{
    $this->curl = curl_init($requestLocation);
}

public function preparePost($postData)
{
    $this->setOption(CURLOPT_POST, 4);
    $this->setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    $this->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $this->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
}

public function execute()
{
    return curl_exec($this->curl);
}

public function setOption($option, $value)
{
    curl_setopt($this->curl, $option, $value);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show something you already have tried?

Comment: No, as if I knew what to try then I'd have done it - I've got it successfully working with the query string appended to the URL but I want to avoid this hard-coding. @C0dekid.php

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646692/how-can-i-make-a-request-with-both-get-and-post-parameters-in-php-with-curl I don't know if it's possible to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and set the access_token value in the header, I'm aware you can do
> this with post, but I'd like to do this for a GET method.

HTTP headers are set in the **same way** for **any** type of request (`POST`, `GET` etc).

The issue with your code is that you set headers in wrong way. [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option expects **numeric-indexed array**, not associative array. Furthermore each array element should be a string in the format `"key: value"`.

So you have to do such changes in your `prepareRequest` method:

```
...
$key = $this->apiConfig->getAccessTokenKey();
$value = $_SESSION[$token];
$curlWrapper->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "$key: $value"
));
...
```